# Can Springs @AliasFor be used for @Import

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I want to create a meta annotation for `@Import` using `AliasFor`. My example looks like

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("Foo")
@Import({})
public @interface MyNewImport {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Import.class, attribute = "value")
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

This doesn't work.
Since JavaDoc says the default value for my annotation and the origin annotation need to be the same, I guess `AliasFor` doesn't work for values with no default values.

Is there a way to create meta annotation for `@Import`?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you have done wrong. Maybe it was the Spring Version. Or not. One thing, I know for sure, the code below works like a charm. I hope it was helpful.

```
@Import({})
@DataJpaTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = Repository.class))
@Inherited
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ServiceJpaTest {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Import.class, attribute = "value")
    Class<?>[] serviceClassesToLoad() default {};

}
```